# Fragment inside a fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, swipe

Is it possible to put a fragment inside a fragment in Android? Consider this: Say, I implement swipeable tabs using Fragment and ViewPager. Now, inside each of these swipeable fragments, I want to implement another fragment - kind of like a fragment nested inside another fragment. But a fragment needs to be attached to an Activity class. So how can this be done?

Comment: you can't attach fragment inside fragment. what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, firstly there are swipeable tabs (which use Fragment). Inside each of these fragments, I want to put in a new (nested) Fragment.

Comment: Check this example: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to put a fragment inside a fragment in Android?

Using the Android Support package's backport of fragments, yes. Also, native fragments on Android 4.2 and higher (API Level 17+) support nested fragments. However, native fragments from API Level 11-16 do not.

> Say, I implement swipeable tabs using Fragment and ViewPager. Now, inside each of these swipeable fragments, I want to implement another fragment - kind of like a fragment nested inside another fragment. But a fragment needs to be attached to an Activity class. So how can this be done?

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrates having fragments in a `ViewPager` and having the `ViewPager` itself be in a fragment. The key is that the `FragmentManager` you supply to your `FragmentPagerAdapter` *must* be the child fragment manager of the outer fragment (i.e., `getChildFragmentManager()`).