# Android: How to implement Tabular UI inside a "fragment"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

There seems to have unique differences in implementation of common tabular UI when it comes to be inside a fragment.

I am looking to find a correct way to have a tabular UI with three to four tabs with each tab containing a listview with custom formatted listitems.

I looked and search many suggestion but they are for other situations like an Activity with a tabular UI and each tab is a fragment or something like that.  Where the difference is, I am having a fragment trying to a tabular UI inside the fragment.

I searched for the closest questions like here but not exactly.
[Fragment inside a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494294/fragment-inside-a-fragment)

I also looked at the Android auto generated project for a tabular UI but its build on tabular UI inside an activity but not a fragment.

So please help out a new developer out if there's actually a solution possible for this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your `minSdkVersion` is 17 or higher, or you are using the fragments backport from the Android Support package, you can use fragments inside of other fragments. This lets you use `ViewPager`, one of the supplied fragment-based `PagerAdapter` implementations (e.g., `FragmentPagerAdapter`), and a tabbed indicator (e.g., [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)) for tabs inside the fragment. Or, you can use a `FragmentTabHost` inside of the fragment.

If your `minSdkVersion` is below 17 *and* you do not want to use the fragments backport, then your primary options are:

- using `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator, but creating your own `PagerAdapter` that uses views for the pages, or
- `TabHost`, again using views as the pages

Comment: thanks commonsman, are any of your android writings or code sample have something implemented similar to what I am asking about?  thx :)

Comment: @YoungBrogrammer: I avoid nested fragments like the plague, but [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrates them in the context of a `ViewPager` being in a fragment and having fragments for pages.

Comment: hi commonsman, i was able to do it, meaning adding a tab UI inside a fragment.  but its not showing the contents of the layout for the fragment inside the tab UI.  heres my clearer situation.  I have a fragmentActivity with has a viewpager having two fragments that allow swiping among the two.  the left fragment inside the viewpager have the tab UI.  as you can imagine, its a bit complex.  i am not able to show the layout for the tab UI fragments.  i suspect that the onCreateView where i created the FragmentTabHost have problems on the setup() call.  please advise

Comment: @YoungBrogrammer: I would advise that you ask a new Stack Overflow question, where you provide relevant snippets of code and a larger explanation of your problem.